# Is it possible to use cache between @babel/cli runs?

Tags: babeljs, babel-cli

When re-running `babel` from the terminal on a group of files which is largely unchanged, babel takes the same amount of time to process them. Is there a way to use caching between different runs of `babel` to speed things up?